# Number Format pointer exception when accessing the application using ipv6 URL

Tags: java, spring-mvc, ipv6

I have made a simple application using Java and Spring MVC(version 4.2.1.RELEASE) and was looking to access it over the internet. But unfortunately, my internet provider(Jio Fiber) doesn't allow port forwarding on ipv4 network. So a solution I came across was to use ipv6 address instead to access the localhost as the ISP allows that.

I followed the solution and successfully accessed my localhost using the ipv6 address. But as soon as I make a server call(say, fetching a list from the db) I get a java.lang.NumberFormatException exception. The stack trace is as follows:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/AgencyAccounting] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "<>"] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "201:8008:78e4:61a4:8a21:6b6c:a853]:8080"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.fromOriginHeader(UriComponentsBuilder.java:353)
    at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.isSameOrigin(WebUtils.java:812)
    at org.springframework.web.cors.DefaultCorsProcessor.processRequest(DefaultCorsProcessor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping$CorsInterceptor.preHandle(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:503)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:954)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help as to what changes i need to make to avoid this error will be highly appreciated.

Pardon me if the question format is wrong, this is my first question here!

Comment: You mean java.lang.NumberFormatException, not NullPointerException, please edit title and text. Where do you define that IPV6 address?

Comment: That is a `NumberFormatException` not a `NullPointerException`. Please specify in your question which version of Spring your are using.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I meant NumberFormatException, not null pointer. Editing the question right away.

@JPMoresmau- not defining the IPV6 address anywhere. this is my 1st time using ipv6.  So not sure where I need to define it. I am just using the url http:/[my global ipv6 address]:8080 to access my application from outside

M.Deinum- 4.2.1 Release is the spring version number. I have updated the same in the question too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are facing similar problem, using the latest spring version solved the issue for me.